# How to destructure an Object from Array with useState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to destructure the filter Object from Array with useState in React, but I can't get it.

```
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState([]);
  const { column, comparison, value } = filter;
  console.log(column); // undefined
```

I tried braces, brackets, and still getting undefined.
Does anyone knows how to get that values?

**The filter object:**

```
  filter: [
    {
      column: 'population',
      comparison: 'greater than',
      value: '100000',
    }
  ]
```

**Console log:**

[image]

Comment: useState initialises the state as what you pass as the argument, in your case that would be an empty array, so none of these values would exist.

Comment: Why is it an array with an object? Wouldn't just an object be easier to handle?

Comment: @PaulMartin I got the filter when I log, the information is there. It should have anyway I guess.

Comment: @Andy that's the structure I got, it would be better for sure using just object, but I can't change it.

Comment: @KelsonBatista where do you place the log? Could you give the code with the log please

Comment: How are you setting `filter`? Is it something passed in as props, redux, context? Is it an API call from a `useEffect`? There's a lot of code missing from your question that would help us debug the problem.

Comment: @Wynell take a look https://imgur.com/a/y9FDKce

Comment: @KelsonBatista based on the three lines of code I can see, you are initialising filter as an empty array, destructuring the empty array and getting 'undefined' when logging the result, which is what I would expect. If you log filter as a fourth line of code, do you still get the object as you would expect?

Comment: @KelsonBatista Could you give the *code*, please. Where in the code do you place the log?

Comment: @Wynell please check https://imgur.com/a/jWEpDVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [latest screenshot of the entire component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwuLU.jpg), the problem is that you are destructuring the `filterByNumericValues` array before it is hydrated with the data. Then your `console.log` has the correct data because it is in the `useEffect` hook AFTER the state has been updated with the data.

Since it looks like you are only using the `column`, `comparison`, and `value` variables in the `checkFilterByNumeric` function, I would destructure the state in that scope.

```js
function checkFilterByNumeric(planet) {
  const { column, comparison, value } = filterByNumericValues[0];

  if (comparison === "maior que") {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You are right @JacobK , it worked!! thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Your filter is an array, not an object. Try:

`const { column, comparison, value } = filter[0];`

Or you can destrcuture your filter array and then do the object destructiong:

```
const [firstItem] = filter;

const { column, comparison, value } = firstItem;
```

Comment: I have already tried this which pops an error: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'column' of 'filter[0]' as it is undefined.

Comment: You need to set a default value that is more than just an empty array. When the component loads your filter array is empty to it can't destruture it

Comment: Nope. That's the point. I got values in filter array, I have already logged it.

Comment: Avi take a look https://imgur.com/a/y9FDKce

Comment: Try passing a dummy object into your default array: const [filter, setFilter] = useState([ { column: '', comparison: '', value: 0 } ]);

Comment: Even passing the dummy I got the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, for example:

```js
const defaultValue = { column: 'empty', comparison: 'empty', value: 0 }
const { column, comparison, value } = filter[0] || defaultValue;
```

Comment: I can't do that because I need the filter data anyway, can't use default value.

Comment: @KelsonBatista if it *ever* displays the default value, then something is wrong with your filtered data (e.g. wrong format or didn't "appear" yet). if you are sure that it is *always* in the correct format, feel free to remove that "or" statement and the default value

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to destructure the object as the first element of the array.

But *how* you're getting `filter` into the component, whether it's via an API request in a `useEffect`, component props, a third-party state management library like Redux, or even React's own context, will determine how you can log/render the information.

The data at the point where you're trying to log/render it simply might not be available at that time.

Here's an small example that passes in `filter` as a component prop, and destructures the object from the array.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  const [ filter, setFilter ] = useState(data);

  // The object that is the first element of the array
  const [{ column, comparison, value }] = filter;

  return <div>{column}</div>;

}

const filter = [{
  column: 'population',
  comparison: 'greater than',
  value: '100000'
}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={filter} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: The filter is coming from Context. If I put in brackets as you did, the output is undefined.

Comment: If it's coming from context why are you using `useState` and not `useContext`? @KelsonBatista